# bbPress replies list

Tags: bbpress

I am trying to get a page to show the list of all the replies that have been made across all forums (e.g. like what would appear if bbPress would allow me to search for a space character which appears in practically every reply). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a shortcode that I can put in my page to show this.

Any ideas about how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

bbPress doesn't have archive for replies implemented. It does have topics archives - www.siteurl.com/**topics**/ and will list all topics. But, for replies, it doesn't have anything that is needed to display replies list, and it needs rewrite rules, code to handle the archives and render it. The only way to do it is to implement all of that, and it is not very complicated, but it will require some work.

Or, you can always create your own template with a normal WP_Query loop to query replies, implement paging and load single reply templates to display replies.

In any case, it requires implementation from scratch.